# How to format a BigDecimal without losing trailing fraction zeros?

Tags: java, formatting, numbers, bigdecimal

NumberFormat doesn't seem to care about the `scale` of a BigDecimal, so given tailing zeros are lost:

```java
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("1234.56789");  //scale=5
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("1234.567890"); //scale=6
a.toString(); //1234.56789
b.toString(); //1234.567890 <-- ✅ decimal place is preserved

nf.format(a); //1.234,56789
nf.format(b); //1.234,56789 <-- ❌ decimal place is lost
```

Comment: Do you want a fixed scale or one that actually depends on the fractions the initial `String` has?

Comment: I'd like them to be formatted with the precision of the respective BigDecimal (as in the example having different scales), preferably without having to reconfigure the NumberFormat for each number.

Answer (score 1):

`NumberFormat` will predictably format a number into a consistent readable value. It uses the exact format rules you set for it.

The only format rules you have set are to start with the rules for the German Local and to include no more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (2,147,483,647) decimal places.

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

The above rules do not include anything to output trailing decimal zeros, the formatter will simply output the number concisely. If you were to format the numbers 1234.56789, 1234.567890, or 1234.567890000000000, they would all consistently output "1.234,56789" since, unless specified otherwise, the default way to format numbers in German is to use `.` as the thousands separator, `,` as the decimal separator, and to not include any leading or trailing zeros.

To see a minimum number of decimal places, you would need to specifically set this number with `setMinimumFractionDigits`.

Comment: Weird having to reconfigure the NumberFormat for each number, although a BigDecimal could tell the formatter its precision (unlike a floating point number).

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a better way:

```java
synchronized (nf) {
  nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(number.scale());
  nf.format(number); //1.234,567890 <-- ✅ decimal place is preserved
}
```

Comment: Unless you are sharing that NumberFormat across threads, there is no need for synchronization.

Comment: I added synchronization to highlight the pitfall, since formatters are often reused and declared as static fields.